# Java: how to trace/monitor GC times for the CMS garbage collector?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm, monitoring

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to monitor the JVM GC for memory exhaustion issues.

With the serial GC, we could just look at the full GC pause times and have a pretty good notion if the JVM was in trouble (if it took more than a few seconds, for example).

CMS seems to behave differently.

When querying `lastGcInfo` from the `java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=ConcurrentMarkSweep` MXBean (via JMX), the reported duration is the sum of all GC steps, and is usually several seconds long. This does not indicate an issue with GC, to the contrary, I've found that too short GC times are usually more of an indicator of trouble (which happens, for example, if the JVM goes into a `CMS-concurrent-mark-start`-> `concurrent mode failure` loop).

I've tried `jstat` as well, which gives the cumulative time spent garbage collecting (unsure if it's for old or newgen GC). This can be graphed, but it's not trivial to use for monitoring purposes. For example, I could parse `jstat -gccause` output and calculate differences over time, and trace+monitor that (e.g. amount of time spent GC'ing over the last X minutes).

I'm using the following JVM arguments for GC logging:

```
-Xloggc:/xxx/gc.log
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintReferenceGC
-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
```

Parsing gc.log is also an option if nothing else is available, but the optimal solution would be to have a java-native way to get at the relevant information.

The information must be machine-readable (to send to monitoring platforms) so visual tools are not an option. I'm running a production environment with a mix of JDK 6/7/8 instances, so version-agnostic solutions are better.

Is there a simple(r) way to monitor CMS garbage collection? What indicators should I be looking at?

Comment: Can you use the JVM options that enable GC logging?

Comment: Yes, I'm using them already (question updated), but gclog parsing is a last-resort solution, I'd like exhaust all idiomatic methods first.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally one wants two things from the CMS concurrent collector

1. the throughput of the concurrent cycle to keep up with the promotion rate, i.e. the objects surviving into the old gen per unit of time
2. enough room in the old generation for objects promoted during a concurrent cycle

So let's say the IHOP is fixed to 70% then you probably are approaching a problem when it reaches >90% at some point. Maybe even earlier if you do some large allocations that don't fit into the young generation or outlive it (that's entirely application-specific).
Additionally you usually want it to spend more time outside the concurrent cycle than in it, although that depends on how tightly you tune the collector, in principle you could have the concurrent cycle running almost all the time, but then you have very little throughput margin and burn a lot of CPU time on concurrent collections.

If you really really want to avoid even the occasional Full GC then you'll need even more safety margins due to fragmentation (CMS is non-compacting). I think this can't be monitored via MX beans, you'll have to to enable some CMS-specific GC logging to get fragmentation info.

Comment: You bring very good insights, can you clarify what you mean with IHOP? I seem to be running more often into concurrent mode failures, but I can't control the applications' object allocation sizes. Do you think reducing NewMem size would help, or are these events only dependent on object sizes?

Comment: IHOP = InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent in general or CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction specifically for CMS. As for your other questions, you need to supply more data (GC logs)

Comment: Actually, you only asked about tracing/monitoring. If you need help with specific behavior of the collector that would be a separate question

Comment: Agreed, it is a bit offtopic for this question.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing GC logs:
If you have already enabled GC logging, I suggest GCViewer - this is an open source tool that can be used to view GC logs and look at parameters like throughput, pause times etc.

For profiling:
I don't see a JDK version mentioned in the question. For JDK 6, I would recommend visualvm to profile an application. For JDK 7/8 I would suggest mission control. You can find these in JDK\lib folder. These tools can be used to see how the application performs over a period of time and during GC (can trigger GC via visualvm UI).

Comment: JMC may not be appropriate since it uses commercial features which require a licence in production environments and may not even be available on openjdk builds.